# Is recreating a proprietary game legal?

Tags: copyright

I was wandering how is that open source projects on GitHub that aim to and in many cases succeed to recreate beloved games from the 2000's are not taken down?

I think it's great and all, but if I am to recreate some NES game for example like "super mario", will my game be illegal to distribute for free, and should I really care if it isn't legal, as long as no one in their right mind is going to sue me for an old 80's game?

Comment: Super Mario, owned by Nintendo, is one of the reasons Nintendo sued RomUniverse.

Answer (score 3):

> will my game be illegal to distribute for free,

Yes

> and should I really care if it isn't legal,

I don’t know if you should care. The worst that can happen is that they can sue you for damage. Depending on how many downloads you get, that can be a lot or a little.

> as long as no one in their right mind is going to sue me for an old 80's game?

People very much in their right mind will sue you. In the US, that’s $750 to $30,000 per download. If you get 1k downloads at $750 that’s $750,000 — well worth rolling the dice on a lawsuit.

Comment: I am not from the US though. What bothers me more is if they (github, sourceforge, a web hosting company etc.) might take down the project

Comment: How does projects like freeablo (Diablo I) and VCMI (Heroes of might and magic 3) don't have trouble?

Comment: @user43800 it is up to the IP owner to sue or request a C&D. Some publishers are notorious for suing for takedowns (Nintendo), others love fan projects as they keep their games *relevant*

Comment: US Statutory danages nare **Not** per download, they ar per work infringed. If one work is copied and the copy is downloaded 10,000 times, that is still onlu 750 to 30,000, or up to $150,000 if the infringement is considered "wilful".  However, the copyright owner could elect toi get actual damages instead of mstuatory damages, and the only limit there is the amout that can be proved. Damages in the millions is perfectly possible in such a case.

Answer (score 3):

There are two reasons they survive.

First, abandonware. When it's unclear who actually owns the IP or when the company owning the IP doesn't exists, nobody can take legal action. This doesn't make it public domain, but it often may as well be.

Second, when companies allow it. It could be because it's not worth the hassle- most tiny fan projects have no negative effects on the IP owner (if the owner even knows about them). It is also done when companies let them. Many see these efforts as genuine appreciation. There can also be significant PR backlash to a big greedy developer bullying a passion project.

Note that Nintendo is well-known for being litigious when it comes to fan projects.

Comment: "Note that Nintendo is well-known for being litigious when it comes to fan projects." AM2R, Pokemon Uranium, etc.

Comment: And also Piracy: RomUniverse

Comment: -1 "*When it's unclear who actually owns the IP or when the company owning the IP doesn't exists, nobody can take legal action*" This is simply untrue. If the company no longer exisxts, whoever got its other property will most likely have gotten the IP as well. In any case someone will own the copyright. Whether such an owner will bother to enforce the copyright cannot be know in advance. Perhaps, maybe not.